# sed command to replace only what's inside a matching set of parentheses

Tags: regex, bash, sed, regex-greedy

I have some old code that looks like `OldUtility.getList(obj)` that has been refactored to be `obj.getList()`. I'm trying to write a `sed` command that will correctly refactor my code. So far, what I have is:

```
sed -i '' 's/\(OldUtility.getList(\)\(.*\))/\2.getList()/g'
```

The problem with this is that it greedily grabs the last closing parenthesis on the line. This means cases like the below do not work:
`OldUtility.getList(obj).size()`
or
`someFunc(OldUtility.getList(obj), otherObj.otherFunc())`

But I don't want it to be non greedy, because it also needs to handle cases like:
`OldUtility.getList(otherObj.toObj())`->`otherObj.toObj().getList()`

So the question is how do I get `\2` to be everything inside the parentheses of the `OldUtility.getList(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getList(...)` may contain any level of nested parenthesis several times, you can't solve this problem with sed (There's no way to know which closing parenthesis is the good one). Here is a pattern you can use with Perl (that has the feature to match nested parenthesis):

```
OldUtility\.getList\(([^()]*+(?:\((?1)\)[^()]*)*+)\)
```

Details:

```
OldUtility\.getList\( # Note that the literal dot and parenthesis must be escaped
(            # open capture group 1
    [^()]*+  # all that is not a parenthesis (zero or more)
    (?:           # open a non capturing group
        \((?1)\)  # recursion with the capture group 1 subpattern
        [^()]*
    )*+           # repeat the non-capturing group (zero or more times)
)
\)
```

Example:

```
echo 'OldUtility.getList(otherObj.toObj().toString())' | perl -pe 's/OldUtility\.getList\(([^()]*+(?:\((?1)\)[^()]*)*+)\)/$1.getList()/g'
```

Comment: @Sean: as you can see the global syntax isn't very different from sed syntax (i.e: `s/.../.../x`). The p parameter print automatically the line. The main thing to understand is the recursion: you open a capture group where the subpattern contains a reference to itself (the `(?1)`).

Comment: I know this is asking a lot - you can refuse. But you'd save me a boatload of time... I also need to be able to refactor one other pattern from `OldUtility.addItem(obj, item)` to be `obj.getList().addItem(item)`, with all the same constraints about supporting nested parens. I'm trying to learn all about perl recursion so that I can adopt your answer, but my guess is that you could do it faster

Comment: @Sean: I forgive you because it's more difficult. Because of the comma that can only occurs in a recursion (inside parenthesis), you need to use a conditional to test if you are in the recursion: `(?(R)A|B)` *(if recursion then A else B)*. Result: `s/OldUtility\.addItem\(((?(R)[^()]*+(?:\((?1)\)[^()]*)*+|[^(),]*+(?:\((?1)\)[^(),]*)*+)),\h*/$1.getList().addItem(/g` demo: https://regex101.com/r/oK4nQ5/1

Comment: If I could, I'd buy you a beer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sean: a `((?(R)er|be))(?1)` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to capture closing parenthesis, you should use `[^)]*` instead of `.*`.

Tested with this:

`echo "OldUtility.getList(otherObj.toObj())       OldUtility.getList(obj).size()      someFunc(OldUtility.getList(obj), otherObj.otherFunc())" | sed -E 's/OldUtility.getList.([^)]*)\)([\)]*)/\1\2.getList()/g'`

The command is `sed -E 's/OldUtility.getList.([^)]*)\)([\)]*)/\1\2.getList()/g'`.

Comment: Thanks - but that's not quite it. If you try: $ echo "OldUtility.getList(otherObj.toObj())" | sed 's/\(OldUtility.getList(\)\([^)]*\))/\2.getList()/g'

You will get:
otherObj.toObj(.getList())

Comment: You're the winner! Thanks. heads up though - the first copy of the command is not the same as the second copy, and seems to be missing some parens. But the second copy works great!

Comment: Actually the second is a copy of the first. The `OldUtility.getList.` should really be `OldUtility\.getList\(`, but that would only matter in extreme edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

you're making it more complicated than needed.

```
$ echo "OldUtility.getList(obj)" | sed -r 's/(OldUtility.getList\()[^)]*\)/\1)/'

OldUtility.getList()
```

I guess I misread the question for the argument extract

```
$ echo "OldUtility.getList(obj)" | sed -r 's/OldUtility(.getList\()([^)]*)\)/\2\1)/'

obj.getList()
```

it's better to capture the string values from the search pattern to eliminate typos and containing the values in one place.

It looks like I missed one more.
This handles one more level, but gets complicated for sed to handle without lookahead.

```
$ echo "OldUtility.getList(otherObj.toObj())" | 
  sed -r 's/OldUtility(.getList\()([^)]+(\(\))?)/\2\1/'

otherObj.toObj().getList()
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood - it needs to result in `obj.getList()`